# Does this regression diagnostic plot mean my data is invalid, and if so how should I go about fixing it?

Tags: r, regression, normal-distribution

[image]

I am doing a project on cloud cover and cosmic rays and have undertaken a regression model in R. Above is the regression diagnostic plot and from the QQ plot I can see that the tails are skewed, meaning it isn't a normal distribution. How significantly will this affect my results? Below is the results, showing no relationship. Would I even expect data from the natural world to follow a normal distribution?

Here is the output for this particular model:

```
Call:
lm(formula = magadanlc ~ magadancr, data = lc)      Output: 1
Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-26.038 -11.044  -1.454  10.202  39.652 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 15.049904  12.494996   1.204    0.229
magadancr    0.002291   0.001492   1.536    0.126

Residual standard error: 13.19 on 314 degrees of freedom
  (2 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.007456,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.004295 
F-statistic: 2.359 on 1 and 314 DF,  p-value: 0.1256
```

Comment: I see few problems in the diagnostics, at least; the very mild deviations from normality assumption seems to be in ways that should cause no problems with the inferences.

Answer (score 1):

The point number 102 might be problematic and you might want to run the model without that point. Other than that, your residuals don't seem very far from normal.  However, the bigger problem is that your $R^2$ is very close to 0. You should look at a scatter plot of your dependent and independent variables and see if there is a nonlinear relationship.  But if you expected a linear relationship here, then ...you didn't get on.

Comment: The r squared is 0.007456. Does this mean that cosmic rays only explain 0.7% of cloud cover? I am not sure how to interpret the output. The p-value is high which I think means it's not reliable? I'm sorry, I don't have a background in Statistics ( study geography)

Comment: I have read online what r2 and p value are and they seem to suggest the same thing. r2 is the percentage of the response variable variation that is explained by a linear model and large p value (which I have) suggests that changes in the predictor are not associated with changes in the response. I'm really confused.

Comment: yes, that is what the $R^2$ means.  The high p value means that, if, in the universe from which this sample was drawn, there was no effect at all, then you would quite often get an $R^2$ at least this high.

Answer (score 0):

You should first check whether magadanlc and magadancr are normally distributed. If they are then apply Pearson's correlation else try Spearman's or Kendall's correlation methods. If they are significantly correlated then only regression exercise should be done (IMHO). I suspect there is no significant correlation between magadanlc and magadancr.

It will be helpful if you can post here the result of tests of normal distribution and correlation coefficients between these 2 variables.

Comment: Why would you need either magadanlc and magadancr to be normally distributed?

Comment: I wanted to check that before choosing the method for determining correlation.

Comment: Why should that be important if the problem is to fit a regression model?

Comment: My impression was that if there is no correlation, there is unlikely to be any benefit in performing regression, at least in majority of common situations. But from your comments, I am getting the sense that I am wrong and I will appreciate if you can explain about this issue.

Comment: You shouldn't assume you're wrong; it's possible there's something you know that I don't, which is why I'm trying to find out why you're suggesting to do these things; if there's a good reason for them, I had better find out. With that in mind, what would you find out from the correlation that the regression wouldn't tell you anyway?

Comment: Generally in statistics texts, testing distribution and correlation are mentioned as initial steps rather than jumping to regression. As it appears in this case, correlation would have indicated that regression is not unnecessary, as these results show.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22765/discussion-between-glen-b-and-rnso).